# How to put list instead of range for "extra_y_ranges" in Bokeh ploting

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

In general to add an extra Y axis we use to use

```
p.extra_y_ranges = {"foo1": Range1d(start=0, end=11)}
```

Here, we are providing the start & end range.

Is there any way to put shorted list instead of range in the field "Range1d"?
Assume I'm having a hexadecimal list as

```
index list = [0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0xF, 0xF0, 0xFF]
```

Comment: did you try to use it? Did you get error message? always put fullerror messag (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text(not screenshot). There ar other useful inormation.

Comment: for you it is list of hexadecimal values but Python/computer keeps it as normal integer values.

Comment: @[SomeOne] Do you find a way to do it? I need the same but with the list of str...